# iTunes order a specific albums tracks by rating

Tags: itunes

I have some albums with various artists in them, and naturally some of them I like more then others.

I want to be able to rate the tracks and then select the album in iTunes and order the tracks simply by rating (so I'll get the best ones first).

So, how do I rate & order the tracks?

Answer (score 0):

Simply click the **Rating** column from the top to change the sorting.

[image]

Comment: Yeah thats what I used to do however that option I can only see in Songs list which is every track in my itunes. I want to be able to do it at the selected Album level. Thanks tho.